# Laravel switch to eloquent search if Scout and Algolia stopped

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am using **Scout and Algolia** for creating my search engine and using the community plan which is limited and free.

I am wondering is there a way to switch back to the normal eloquent using `WHERE LIKE` if a problem happened in **Scout or Algolia** like subscription?

Comment: Yes sure, just change the driver at runtime using the config helper

Comment: Yes but how I detect if there is a problem and how to change the driver?

Comment: Please add your comment in a detailed answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decorate algolia engine with fallback decorator and switch to fallback if an error occurs.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {

        resolve(EngineManager::class)->extend(AppSearchEngine::class, function () {
            $origin = new AlgoliaEngine();
            $fallback = new MySQLEngine();
            return new FallbackEngine($origin, $fallback);
        });
    }
}

class FallbackEngine extends Engine {
...
    public function search(Builder $builder)
    {
        try {
            return $this->origin->search();
        } ($e \Excheption) {
            return $this->fallback->search();
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Just to complete this, you can also simply use a similar `try { ... } catch` block wherever you perform the `search` usually, and implement the fallback method there.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can use normal query to search results in laravel.

```
ModelName::query()
   ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") 
   ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") 
   ->get();
```

Or Simply build a macro to search in laravel

https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel

Comment: Man I know how to search using `where like` but my question is different.