# Elequent fallback for Laravel Scout

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-scout

I have a project in Laravel with Scout using Algolia and was wondering if there was a way to add a fallback to Eloquent search if the Algolia connection fails. I know I can just switch the driver from Scout, but I'm worried about Algolia failing and want an extra fallback on the off chance our Algolia connection fails

Comment: Related post, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943155/laravel-switch-to-eloquent-search-if-scout-and-algolia-stopped?rq=2